Python loop outputting different answers to the same inputs and not ending on correct line
I'm trying to make the program stop only when the user inputs 'n' at the input that asks if they want to calculate another population. When putting in the same outputs for the 2nd time with the loop, it gives me a different output. The output also doesn't stop after inputting 'n' in cal_new_pop = input("Do you want to calculate another population? "). The program still has some problems with outputting the correct answer for some inputs at the start.
I've tried changing the indentations on the bottom few lines but it causes an infinite loop or too many output lines. I've also tried changing the math but it gives answers that are different from what they are supposed to be. I would also like to note that the inputs 200 and 1 are supposed to give 216 as an output. Another is 100 and 10 which is supposed to give 214 but gives 218 instead.
start_pop = int(input("How many jackalopes do you have? "))
num_gens = int(input("How many generations do you want to wait? "))
cal_new_pop = 'y'
births = 0
deaths = 0
next_gen_pop = 0

while cal_new_pop != 'n':
  if num_gens < 1:
    births = round(start_pop * 0.1)
    deaths = round(start_pop * 0.02)
    next_gen_pop = (start_pop + births) - deaths
  else:
    for _ in range(num_gens+1):
      births = round(births + next_gen_pop * 0.1)
      deaths = round(deaths + next_gen_pop * 0.02)
      next_gen_pop = (start_pop + births) - deaths
    end_pop = (start_pop + births) - deaths
    print(f"If you start with {start_pop} jackalopes "
        f"\nand wait {num_gens} generations,"
         f"\nyou'll end up with a total of {end_pop} jackalopes.\n")

  cal_new_pop = input("Do you want to calculate another population? ")
  if cal_new_pop == 'y':
    start_pop = int(input("How many jackalopes do you have? "))
    num_gens = int(input("How many generations do you want to wait? "))

Here is an output:
How many jackalopes do you have? 200
How many generations do you want to wait? 1
If you start with 200 jackalopes 
and wait 1 generations,
you'll end up with a total of 216 jackalopes.

Do you want to calculate another population? y
How many jackalopes do you have? 200
How many generations do you want to wait? 1
If you start with 200 jackalopes 
and wait 1 generations,
you'll end up with a total of 252 jackalopes.

Do you want to calculate another population? n
How many generations do you want to wait? 1  
 


Not reproducible. It stops when you input n. [ask] and [mre]

The variables births, deaths, and next_gen_pop should be initialized inside your while loop.  When I moved them right after the "while" statement, I got consistent reponses.

You are not resetting births, deaths, or next_gen_pop inside the while loop. Because of this, after each iteration, the number will change compared to the previous iteration.

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
